# Object in Array is not recognised as having "methods"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

I got my application working Awhile back, but after completely and accidentally deleting it, I have tried to create it from square one. unfortunately my rewritten program is a bit cranky; does anyone see or know the possible sources of error? Also, my if statements are acting up.

```
-(void)loadAnnotations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
    iProspectLiteAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iProspectLiteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableArray *mines =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *) appDelegate.mines];
    BOOL gold = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"goldControl"];
    BOOL silver = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"silverControl"];
    BOOL copper = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"copperControl"];
    for(id mine in mines)
    {
    NSLog(@"in the loop");
    workingCoordinate.latitude = [[mine latitudeInitial] doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude = [[mine longitudeInitial] doubleValue];
    iProspectLiteAnnotation *tempMine = [[iProspectLiteAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [tempMine setTite:[mine mineName]];

    if ([[mine commodity] isEqualToString:@"Gold"] && [gold == YES])
    {
        [tempMine setAnnotationType:iProspectLiteAnnotationTypeGold];
        [mapView addAnnotation:tempMine];
    }
    if([[mine commodity] isEqualToString:@"Silver"] && [silver == YES])
    {
        [tempMine setAnnotationType:iProspectLiteAnnotationTypeSilver];
    }
    if([[mine commodity] isEqualToString:@"Copper"] && [copper == YES])
    {
        [tempMine setAnnotationType:iProspectLiteAnnotationTypeCopper];
    }
}
[mines dealloc];
}
```

where the workingCoordinate.latitude = [[mine latitudeInitial] doubleValue], as well as the longitude, and [mine mineName],it says " No '-latitudeInitiallongitudeInitial' method found" or the mineName/LongitudeInitial. 
also, it complains about : before ] at all the if statement lines. I don't see any errors, do you?

Comment: AGH!!!! **NEVER** invoke `dealloc` yourself!  Always use (`auto`)`release`!

Comment: Except that, in this case you can just do `NSArray* mines = appDelegate.mines;` instead of allocating a new array and then you won't need to release mines.

Comment: in this program, every time the view switches from the information view a new mines array is copied and sorted through, hence the need to (i guess release in this case) the mines array. But now that I think about it theres probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an iterator that is giving you objects of type `id` - calling a method on those will often confuse a compiler. Are you able to cast them to a known type?

Like `for(MineType* mine in mines)`?

And

```
[tempMine setTite:[mine mineName]];
```

Is that a typo? My guess is you would be calling that method `setTitle`.

Comment: Ok the setTite was a typo. that much I fixed. And your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

i think changing the object type of mine object in the for loop to whatever custom class you have with latitudeInitial, longitudeInitial, mineName properties/methods should solve this.